# Prove $\frac{1}{x}$ uniformly continuous on $(2,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Is this okay to prove $\frac{1}{x}$ uniformly continuous on $(2,\infty)$

Let $\epsilon>0$ choose $\delta=4\epsilon.$

Then $|x-y|<\delta \implies |\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}|<\epsilon.$

Is it okay to choose $4$ even though $2$ is not in the domain of the function?

Comment: Since this issue is not part of the question, I confine my remark to a comment.
If I was attacking this problem, the first thing that I would do is ask myself,
is the conjecture true; and if so **why**?  The intuitive difference between
uniform continuity and continuity is that with continuity at a specific point
$x$, the [choose $\epsilon$ then find $\delta$] requirement is **allowed** to
 be tailored to a specific value of $x$.  ...see next comment

Comment: With uniform continuity, you must demonstrate a **universal algorithm** for 
satisfying the [choose $\epsilon$ then find $\delta$] requirement, that will
work against **any** $x$.  Taking $f(x) = (1/x),$ it is clear that as $x$ increases, 
|f'(x)| is decreasing.  Intuitively (i.e. **non-rigorously** - you would need
to formally prove this) if you can find a [choose $\epsilon$ then find $\delta$]
algorithm that works at $x=2$, then it should work for any $x > 2.$  This is 
**why** the function is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is okay. It doesn't matter whether $\delta$ itself is or is not an element of the domain.

In the definition of uniform continuity, the numerical value of $\delta$ does not represent an element of the domain. Instead it represents *distance* between elements of the domain. For example, when you read the inequality "$|x-y|<\delta$" out loud to yourself, you should be saying "the distance between $x$ and $y$ is less than $\delta$".

Notice in particular: You can find a pair of elements of the domain $(2,\infty)$ which have distance $1$; you can find a pair which have distance $.000001$; and in fact if someone hands you any positive number whatsoever, no matter how small, you can find a pair of elements of the domain $(2,\infty)$ which have that distance.

Comment: So my answer is okay or not?

Comment: I rewrote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is uniform continuous over $(a, +\infty)$ for any $a > 0$, but not $a = 0$.

For any $\epsilon>0$, let $\delta = a^2 \epsilon$.
Since
$$|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y}| = \frac{|x-y|}{|x||y|}$$. When $|x - y| < \delta$, we know $|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y}| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Indeed the function is _Lipschitz-continuous_ over $(a,\infty)$ if $a>0$.